# How to upload all Android photo gallery Albums to Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I currently have my phone's digital photos uploading to my Dropbox "Camera Uploads" folder, but I recently discovered that some of the folders in my Gallery > Albums are not uploading. For example, I downloaded photos from the Disneyland app to my Android. Those photos were saved in my Gallery/Albums in a folder called "Disney". Those photos have not uploaded to Dropbox. Meanwhile, other folders in Gallery/Albums (such as my Screenshots folder) have uploaded to Dropbox.

Why would some folders not upload? Is there anything I can do too ensure that every single Album/photo is uploaded to Dropbox automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question.  This is what I learned from Dropbox Community

"The automatic camera upload feature uploads all photos and videos from the "Camera" and "Screenshots" albums on your device."

See https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-files-folders/Phone-Galleries-and-Camera-Uploads/td-p/539326